# Using aggregations to group elements of my array which are present in mongoDB but returning nothing?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Hello all i have an array of items now i want to know which of them are present in mongoDB now for that i read that i should use aggregations now i am using aggregations but it is not returning anything can anyone please point out what am i doing wrong below is my query given

```
userfavouritemodel.aggregate([
          { "$match": { "offers": {"$in": my_array}, "mobile_no":"1234567890" } },
          { $unwind: "$offers" },
          { "$group" : { "_id":"$_id","matched_elements":{ "$addToSet": "$offers" }}}
          ], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              return;
            }
            console.log('user favourites');
            console.log(result);
          });
```

**UPDATE-** Example of documents in my database

```
 { "_id" : "566d6add9384223014ebcf43" , "mobile_no" : "1234567890" , "total_offers" : 4 , "offers" : [ "565ae5d8fff110dc18718b7c" , "565ae479fff110dc18718b7a" , "565ae479fff110dc18718b7a" , "5644a9339bf660501f15254e"]}
```

Comment: Could you add an exemple of document in your collection?

Comment: @ConstantinGuay pls have a relook at my problem ??

Comment: what are you trying to do? Are you trying to get all the offers for the mobile_no:1234567890?

Comment: for the mobile number i wanna see which of my array elements are present in that mobile_no's offers column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this will return the offers that matches the mobile number and the offers within the array:

> ```
> db.collection.aggregate([
>                {$match:{mobile_no:"1234567890"}},
>                {$project:{_id:0, offers:1}},
>                {$unwind:"$offers"}, 
>                {$match:{offers:{$in:["565ae479fff110dc18718b7a", "565ae5d8fff110dc18718b7c"]}}}]);
> ```

Comment: i want this to return array elements if they are present in document whose mobile_no: "1234567890"

Comment: previous one is also working what is the difference between the two ?? and hey thanks a lot man for the answer :)

Comment: Previous one, will return ALL the offers not only the one which is present in your array. This one will only returns only the offers that is present in your array. Glad it worked :)

Comment: no previous one is returning only array elelments which are present ??

Comment: As per my testing, the first version would return all the offers even if only one matched from within your array. Thats why I updated it. Am I missing something?

Comment: no in my case suppose i have a document "mobile_no": "1234567890", "offers": ["1", "2", "3"] now if i would search for { $match:
                { 
                  $and:[ {mobile_no:"1234567890"}, 
                    {offers: {$in: ["1", "4", "5"]}}
                  ]} },  Now this is returning offers 1 only so i guess it is working completely fine can you run for this case and see what is in your case it is returning ??